# check the url of current page in if statement

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

so i have this button that appears on multiple pages all leading to the parent page. But now - when i reach the parent page i still have the button showing. I want to remove/hide the button when on the parent page.

Is it possible that i could check my current page url and check to see if it the parent page?

```
<a id="element" href="/Pages/@ViewBag.ElementId" class="btn">
      <i>Home</i>
</a>
```

thinking using an if statement surrounding the  tag

Comment: Is this APS.NET? You could hide/show the link in the PageLoad event handler, depending on Request.Url. Alternatively, in JavaScript, you have document.URL.

Comment: @kol yes it is Asp.net - i was thinking if i could use 'HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath' in an if statement?

Comment: You want something like [this](http://jsbin.com/xotosode/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do your check in the code behind page, you can always execute the code below during the page load event.

```
if (Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.LocalPath) == "ParentPage.aspx")
{ element.visible = false; }
else
{ element.visible = true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah that's what the window.location variable is for see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Answer (score 0):

When you are in your parent page, what is the ElementId value ?
I assume it can be null, so you may be able to check this value before displaying your button

```
@if(ViewBag.ElementId != null){
  <a id="element" href="/Pages/@ViewBag.ElementId" class="btn">
    <i>Home</i>
  </a>
}
else { //TODO... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ASP.NET MVC to me.

```
@if (!Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/i/dont/want/this"))
{
    <a id="element" href="/Pages/@ViewBag.ElementId" class="btn">
        <i>Home</i>
    </a>
}
```